# Wrong parse date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I get date from html5 input `dateTime`

```
var t = new Date("2017-10-13T00:00")
```

on Windows Chrome

```
Fri Oct 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300
```

on Linux Chrome

```
Fri Oct 13 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0300
```

can I fixed it?

Comment: may help https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=520783

Comment: Ran your code on a mac, got: `Fri Oct 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. But that is quite correct as I am in CEST timezone